# System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse) while deploying spring rest project?

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven

I am geting this error while Deploying spring rest project using maven in eclipse with tomcat 9.0 server.

**DemoAppConfig.java**

```
package com.pal.springdemo.rest.conf;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.pal.springdemo.rest")
public class DemoAppConfig {

}
```

**MyDispatcherServletInitilizer**

```java
package com.pal.springdemo.rest.conf;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitilizer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class [] {DemoAppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String [] {"/"};
    }

 }
```

**PalController**

```
package com.pal.springdemo.rest.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class Travel {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sethello() {
        System.out.println("hello from test");
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

> This is the error i am getting with short message:
>   The application isimproperly formatted.COntact the application vendor
>   for assistance.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34209
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://localhost:8080/sanjeet_pal_spring_rest_api/test/hello

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://localhost:8080/sanjeet_pal_spring_rest_api/test/hello resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception reading manifest from http://localhost:8080/sanjeet_pal_spring_rest_api/test/hello: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [09-Feb-20 10:22:17 PM] : Activation of http://localhost:8080/sanjeet_pal_spring_rest_api/test/hello has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [09-Feb-20 10:22:18 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Exception reading manifest from http://localhost:8080/sanjeet_pal_spring_rest_api/test/hello: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Xml.XmlException
        - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
        - Source: System.Xml
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read()
            at System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read()
            at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

It work fine index.jsp without any error but give error while going to rest controller Mapped link..

project reference: https://github.com/sanjeet123456789/spring_project/tree/master/sanjeet_pal_spring_rest_api